# Converting chars into ASCII returns numbers too big

Tags: c++, ascii, xor, c-strings, stringstream

So I have this function that XORes a string and then it turns it into a format like this:

```
\x55\x1\x53\x21...
```

But the problem is that the function firstly returned negative values, but I fixed that by making it from a CHAR into a UCHAR, but now it starts giving me values that are too big and the compiler doesn't let me compile because of it. Any thoughts of why this would happen? Couldn't find anything about it online.

```
__inline char* EncryptString(const char* String, const char* Key)
{
    char* szEncrypted = new char[lstrlenA(String) + 1];
    memcpy(szEncrypted, String, lstrlenA(String) + 1);

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < lstrlenA(String); ++i)
        szEncrypted[i] = String[i] ^ Key[i % (lstrlenA(Key))];

    std::stringstream lpStream;

    for (int32_t i = 0; i < lstrlenA(szEncrypted); ++i)
    {
        char cCharInd       = szEncrypted[i];
        UINT nCharNum       = UINT(cCharInd);

        lpStream << "\\x" << std::hex << nCharNum;
    }

    std::string sHexEscaped = lpStream.str();
    lpStream.clear();

    delete[] szEncrypted;

    char* szReturn = new char[sHexEscaped.length() + 1];
    memcpy(szReturn, sHexEscaped.c_str(), sHexEscaped.length() + 1);

    return szReturn;
}
```

Comment: Try to do a simple experiment: `char cCharInd       = '\x90'; UINT nCharNum       = UINT(cCharInd);` Now, print the value of `nCharNum`, to `std::cout`, or something, and see what you get, then see if you can figure out why.

Comment: You don't copy the terminator with your `memcpy` call.

Comment: I think I get what the problem is thanks to @SamVarshavchik. Basically I wanted to use \x because when I XOR them normally i get some characters I can't copy back into a C++ string in order to decrypt them later. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Another major problem: `sizeof(Key) / sizeof(char)` will *not* do what you probably think it does. Since `Key` is a pointer, doing `sizeof(Key)` will return the size of *the pointer*, and not what it points to. The result of `sizeof(Key) / sizeof(char)` will be either `4` or `8` depending on if you're on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Edited thy code

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the type `char` can be signed or unsinged (depends on compiler). I think the following code helps you:

```
const unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>( szEncrypted[i] );
const unsigned int code = uc;
lpStream << "\\x" << std::hex << code;
```

P.S. Looks like you actually don't need to use temporary buffer szEncrypted.

**UPDATE:**

I tried to demonstrate how such encryption may works in code below (the source file encoding is Windows-1251). You also have to know that encrypted string may contain `\0` bytes, so, to calculate the length of encrypted string you would probably use something like this: `const char rawString[] = "\xf\x55\x0\x1e\x22\x98\x20\x1e\x2b\x4b\x12"; const int rawSize = sizeof( raw ) - 1;`

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string EncryptString( const char* String, const char* Key )
{
    std::stringstream lpStream;
    const int keyLength = strlen( Key );
    for( int i = 0; String[i] != '\0'; i++ ) {
        char ec = String[i] ^ Key[i % keyLength];
        unsigned char uc = static_cast<unsigned char>( ec );
        lpStream << "\\x" << std::hex << static_cast<unsigned int>( uc );
    }
    return lpStream.str();
}

void DecryptString( string& String, const char* Key )
{
    const int keyLength = strlen( Key );
    for( string::size_type i = 0; i < String.length(); i++ ) {
        String[i] ^= Key[i % keyLength];
    }
}

int main()
{
    system( "ChCp 1251" );
    const char* key = "Пётр";
    cout << EncryptString( "Антон Тодуа", key ) << endl;
    const char raw[] = "\xf\x55\x0\x1e\x22\x98\x20\x1e\x2b\x4b\x12";
    string data( raw, sizeof( raw ) - 1 );
    DecryptString( data, key );
    cout << data << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate but I completely lost track of what I wanted to do with my code and it got so messy. I just wanted to have a code that could XOR my string with a key, I could copy it and then paste it into the program again and decrypt it. The problem is that I could not paste it into my code because the UNICODE characters wouldn't copy so I needed to find a way to copy them. Any ideas? **EDIT:** szEncrypted? I think you meant szReturn maybe

Comment: @Itsenough1 Please try to use code from my updated answer.

Comment: May take some time ti understand what is going on in the code so hang on